# Chrome notification

Tags: javascript, html

Today, I wrote a code JS that create Chrome notification.
This notification should pop out when the live stream freecodecamp is turned on.
Currently, it only pops when I pressed on the right corner of the browser (there are all plugins).

I just need some information.

-How to make a notification pop-up when live stream is turned on?

-How to make a notification pop-up when live stream is already on but user  has just turned on the browser?

-How to make that when user click on the plugin on the right corner each time do not pop up this notification itself, even if the live stream is offline?

-How can I connect script JS with href. After click on notification takes user to the new page?

If You dont understand what I want to do just say that and I will try to explain.

```
var options= {
    type: "basic",
    title: "it works!",
    message: "message",
    iconUrl: "icon.jpeg",

};



$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/freecodecamp',
    headers: {
      'client-ID' : '3g6rgcf48hcrlo3abbf7k3q13aqje0'
    },
    success: function(data6){
        if(data6.stream!==null){

            chrome.notifications.create(options, callback);

function callback(data5) {
    if(data5.stream===null){
    console.log("offline")
    }
    else {
        console.log('online')
    }
}  
        }



        else{
            console.log('error')
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Ideally, you should narrow down your problem to several specific questions (asked seperately). You're currently asking how to build an entire system, which isn't a great fit for a StackOverflow post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets break it down one by one.

**-How to make a notification pop-up when live stream is turned on?**

You need to pool the api which gives you status of stream(s) that is turned on.

**-How to make a notification pop-up when live stream is already on but user has just turned on the browser?**

Plesae see the point#1 response.

**-How to make that when user click on the plugin on the right corner each time do not pop up this notification itself, even if the live stream is offline?**

You need to place a logic on click events or start plugin event to handle this situation.

**-How can I connect script JS with href. After click on notification takes user to the new page?**

In href set either "#" or "javascript:void(0);" without quote and attach a click event with it. In the attach event callback function you can write your business logic.

Comment: "-How to make a notification pop-up when live stream is turned on?

You need to pool the api which gives you status of stream(s) that is turned on."

But actually I did this  in my code: `  success: function(data6){
        if(data6.stream!==null){

            chrome.notifications.create(options, callback); `          It works when stream is on but only when user clicks on plugin. It should pops up even when the user browses the internet